# (Rails) Facebook callbacks RuntimeError with gem devise omniauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, heroku, devise, omniauth

I use gem devise and omniauth for facebook account login to my app, 
when I in development environment, it runs well and with no errors. 
But when I push to Heroku production environment, the facebook login callbacks would be RuntimeError. 
The most strange thing bothering me is that I run it totally okay in local development environment. but it goes wrong on Heroku.

PS I do remember to add Heroku config:set facebook_app_id and facebooK_secret settings parameters.   I don't know what happen.  Thanks for helping me.

The following are error logs.

(Summary)

```
MESSAGE   100.0%    RuntimeError: --- !ruby/hash:OmniAuth::AuthHash provider: facebook uid: '100002129143525' info: !ruby/hash:OmniAuth::AuthHash::InfoHash nickname: yettie.lin email: yettie.lin@gmail.com name: Yettie Lin first_name: Yettie last_name: Lin image: http://graph.facebook.com/100002129143525/picture?type=square urls: !ruby/hash:OmniAuth::AuthHash Facebook: https://www.facebook.com/yettie.lin credentials: !ruby/hash:OmniAuth::AuthHash token: CAAUfP3P53roBAGaYbjPq89MsvR5Yy2FEMuK42PhQiZCgKAHy6paXQgTkhtlD7zmPmvi7yVlDsB5UgkNZAKkCSbmAbc3mlWgi95zIhAhDDpapmIIPSKpFnPuDgwqTgGsHlePpK7fGebnCbCfAZBysQ75wMZBJEwWKHXN0gMjQnBoMQMXXBUTDxS4XHEVoMisZD expires_at: 1394891723 expires: true extra: !ruby/hash:OmniAuth::AuthHash raw_info: !ruby/hash:OmniAuth::AuthHash id: '100002129143525' name: Yettie Lin first_name: Yettie last_name: Lin link: https://www.facebook.com/yettie.lin gender: male email: yettie.lin@gmail.com timezone: 8 locale: zh_TW updated_time: '2014-01-11T15:52:06+0000' username: yettie.lin
ERROR CLASS RuntimeError
URL http://dan-group-post.herokuapp.com/users/auth/facebook/callback?code=AQCP49MdSSopYTAYIOM-J3WILj2mmZ8-67bEVlPgY-4TXn6tWJBiesqkdLutnAoNvStnplOncQLh_PFOByCMJkdaAnC6j6TTn5hBFL369JRTsAH4xwvk44CBBF74SyQkfwdwaCDBGQvDbI2e6CgVqV19CNT8fX_AyMant_luLB6fHhIzhqnn8wKMYTJKZlr27n6fcRfP91zwU3QuLHs6IbkjE4JqdHFi8W2OjwVpAHZReBC_olFZm1vLAXaGZDPQIJWUWzKMlyio5WPIuyIl9yxtgmT3n1CAlGiFdg89SwRcY18cGa67AZzcW3S6IUD7zVQ&state=1ba64f8c892236e20691beab5d42ed97c93a10ddfd893576
    WHERE   users/omniauth_callbacks#facebook
    OCCURRED    Jan 15 01:16:15
    SIMILAR 0
    BROWSER 100.0%  Chrome 31.0.1650.63 (OS X 10.9.1)
    TENANT  100.0%  dan-group-post.herokuapp.com
    APP SERVER  c3f4241c-8efa-4371-b08d-9fd7e48d0e53
    FRAMEWORK   Rails: 4.0.0
    REL. DIRECTORY  /app
```

backtrace :

```
app/controllers/user/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb:3→ facebook
actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4→ send_action
```

parameters:

```
ATEWAY_INTERFACE    CGI/1.1
HTTP_ACCEPT text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING    gzip,deflate,sdch
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE    zh-TW,zh;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL  max-age=0
HTTP_CONNECTION close
HTTP_HOST   dan-group-post.herokuapp.com
HTTP_USER_AGENT Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.63 Safari/537.36
HTTP_VERSION    HTTP/1.1
HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR    112.105.105.89
HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PORT   80
HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO  http
HTTP_X_REQUEST_START    1389719774638
ORIGINAL_FULLPATH   /users/auth/facebook/callback?code=AQCP49MdSSopYTAYIOM-J3WILj2mmZ8-67bEVlPgY-4TXn6tWJBiesqkdLutnAoNvStnplOncQLh_PFOByCMJkdaAnC6j6TTn5hBFL369JRTsAH4xwvk44CBBF74SyQkfwdwaCDBGQvDbI2e6CgVqV19CNT8fX_AyMant_luLB6fHhIzhqnn8wKMYTJKZlr27n6fcRfP91zwU3QuLHs6IbkjE4JqdHFi8W2OjwVpAHZReBC_olFZm1vLAXaGZDPQIJWUWzKMlyio5WPIuyIl9yxtgmT3n1CAlGiFdg89SwRcY18cGa67AZzcW3S6IUD7zVQ&state=1ba64f8c892236e20691beab5d42ed97c93a10ddfd893576
ORIGINAL_SCRIPT_NAME    
PATH_INFO   /users/auth/facebook/callback
QUERY_STRING    code=AQCP49MdSSopYTAYIOM-J3WILj2mmZ8-67bEVlPgY-4TXn6tWJBiesqkdLutnAoNvStnplOncQLh_PFOByCMJkdaAnC6j6TTn5hBFL369JRTsAH4xwvk44CBBF74SyQkfwdwaCDBGQvDbI2e6CgVqV19CNT8fX_AyMant_luLB6fHhIzhqnn8wKMYTJKZlr27n6fcRfP91zwU3QuLHs6IbkjE4JqdHFi8W2OjwVpAHZReBC_olFZm1vLAXaGZDPQIJWUWzKMlyio5WPIuyIl9yxtgmT3n1CAlGiFdg89SwRcY18cGa67AZzcW3S6IUD7zVQ&state=1ba64f8c892236e20691beab5d42ed97c93a10ddfd893576
REMOTE_ADDR 10.10.155.37
REMOTE_HOST 10.10.155.37
REQUEST_METHOD  GET
REQUEST_PATH    /users/auth/facebook/callback
REQUEST_URI http://dan-group-post.herokuapp.com/users/auth/facebook/callback?code=AQCP49MdSSopYTAYIOM-J3WILj2mmZ8-67bEVlPgY-4TXn6tWJBiesqkdLutnAoNvStnplOncQLh_PFOByCMJkdaAnC6j6TTn5hBFL369JRTsAH4xwvk44CBBF74SyQkfwdwaCDBGQvDbI2e6CgVqV19CNT8fX_AyMant_luLB6fHhIzhqnn8wKMYTJKZlr27n6fcRfP91zwU3QuLHs6IbkjE4JqdHFi8W2OjwVpAHZReBC_olFZm1vLAXaGZDPQIJWUWzKMlyio5WPIuyIl9yxtgmT3n1CAlGiFdg89SwRcY18cGa67AZzcW3S6IUD7zVQ&state=1ba64f8c892236e20691beab5d42ed97c93a10ddfd893576
ROUTES_69923930432140_SCRIPT_NAME   
SCRIPT_NAME 
SERVER_NAME dan-group-post.herokuapp.com
SERVER_PORT 80
SERVER_PROTOCOL HTTP/1.1
SERVER_SOFTWARE WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.0.0/2013-11-22)
ACTION_DISPATCH_PARAMETER_FILTER    ["password"]
ACTION_DISPATCH_REDIRECT_FILTER []
ACTION_DISPATCH_REMOTE_IP   112.105.105.89
ACTION_DISPATCH_REQUEST_CONTENT_TYPE    
ACTION_DISPATCH_REQUEST_FORMATS ["text/html"]
ACTION_DISPATCH_REQUEST_ID  65857625-8e21-40fd-82fb-5870f8c70d33
ACTION_DISPATCH_REQUEST_PARAMETERS  {"code"=>"AQCP49MdSSopYTAYIOM-J3WILj2mmZ8-67bEVlPgY-4TXn6tWJBiesqkdLutnAoNvStnplOncQLh_PFOByCMJkdaAnC6j6TTn5hBFL369JRTsAH4xwvk44CBBF74SyQkfwdwaCDBGQvDbI2e6CgVqV19CNT8fX_AyMant_luLB6fHhIzhqnn8wKMYTJKZlr27n6fcRfP91zwU3QuLHs6IbkjE4JqdHFi8W2OjwVpAHZReBC_olFZm1vLAXaGZDPQIJWUWzKMlyio5WPIuyIl9yxtgmT3n1CAlGiFdg89SwRcY18cGa67AZzcW3S6IUD7zVQ", "state"=>"1ba64f8c892236e20691beab5d42ed97c93a10ddfd893576", "controller"=>"users/omniauth_callbacks", "action"=>"facebook"}
ACTION_DISPATCH_REQUEST_PATH_PARAMETERS {"controller"=>"users/omniauth_callbacks", "action"=>"facebook"}
ACTION_DISPATCH_REQUEST_QUERY_PARAMETERS    {"code"=>"AQCP49MdSSopYTAYIOM-J3WILj2mmZ8-67bEVlPgY-4TXn6tWJBiesqkdLutnAoNvStnplOncQLh_PFOByCMJkdaAnC6j6TTn5hBFL369JRTsAH4xwvk44CBBF74SyQkfwdwaCDBGQvDbI2e6CgVqV19CNT8fX_AyMant_luLB6fHhIzhqnn8wKMYTJKZlr27n6fcRfP91zwU3QuLHs6IbkjE4JqdHFi8W2OjwVpAHZReBC_olFZm1vLAXaGZDPQIJWUWzKMlyio5WPIuyIl9yxtgmT3n1CAlGiFdg89SwRcY18cGa67AZzcW3S6IUD7zVQ", "state"=>"1ba64f8c892236e20691beab5d42ed97c93a10ddfd893576"}
ACTION_DISPATCH_REQUEST_REQUEST_PARAMETERS  
ACTION_DISPATCH_SHOW_DETAILED_EXCEPTIONS    false
ACTION_DISPATCH_SHOW_EXCEPTIONS true
DEVISE_MAPPING  #<Devise::Mapping:0x007f30dca29e28>
DEVISE_SKIP_TIMEOUT true
OMNIAUTH_AUTH   {"provider"=>"facebook", "uid"=>"100002129143525", "info"=>{"nickname"=>"yettie.lin", "email"=>"yettie.lin@gmail.com", "name"=>"Yettie Lin", "first_name"=>"Yettie", "last_name"=>"Lin", "image"=>"http://graph.facebook.com/100002129143525/picture?type=square", "urls"=>{"Facebook"=>"https://www.facebook.com/yettie.lin"}}, "credentials"=>{"token"=>"CAAUfP3P53roBAGaYbjPq89MsvR5Yy2FEMuK42PhQiZCgKAHy6paXQgTkhtlD7zmPmvi7yVlDsB5UgkNZAKkCSbmAbc3mlWgi95zIhAhDDpapmIIPSKpFnPuDgwqTgGsHlePpK7fGebnCbCfAZBysQ75wMZBJEwWKHXN0gMjQnBoMQMXXBUTDxS4XHEVoMisZD", "expires_at"=>"1394891723", "expires"=>"true"}, "extra"=>{"raw_info"=>{"id"=>"100002129143525", "name"=>"Yettie Lin", "first_name"=>"Yettie", "last_name"=>"Lin", "link"=>"https://www.facebook.com/yettie.lin", "gender"=>"male", "email"=>"yettie.lin@gmail.com", "timezone"=>"8", "locale"=>"zh_TW", "updated_time"=>"2014-01-11T15:52:06+0000", "username"=>"yettie.lin"}}}
OMNIAUTH_ORIGIN http://dan-group-post.herokuapp.com/
OMNIAUTH_PARAMS 
OMNIAUTH_STRATEGY   #<OmniAuth::Strategies::Facebook:0x007f30e05e9648>
RACK_MULTIPROCESS   false
RACK_MULTITHREAD    false
RACK_REQUEST_QUERY_HASH {"code"=>"AQCP49MdSSopYTAYIOM-J3WILj2mmZ8-67bEVlPgY-4TXn6tWJBiesqkdLutnAoNvStnplOncQLh_PFOByCMJkdaAnC6j6TTn5hBFL369JRTsAH4xwvk44CBBF74SyQkfwdwaCDBGQvDbI2e6CgVqV19CNT8fX_AyMant_luLB6fHhIzhqnn8wKMYTJKZlr27n6fcRfP91zwU3QuLHs6IbkjE4JqdHFi8W2OjwVpAHZReBC_olFZm1vLAXaGZDPQIJWUWzKMlyio5WPIuyIl9yxtgmT3n1CAlGiFdg89SwRcY18cGa67AZzcW3S6IUD7zVQ", "state"=>"1ba64f8c892236e20691beab5d42ed97c93a10ddfd893576"}
RACK_REQUEST_QUERY_STRING   code=AQCP49MdSSopYTAYIOM-J3WILj2mmZ8-67bEVlPgY-4TXn6tWJBiesqkdLutnAoNvStnplOncQLh_PFOByCMJkdaAnC6j6TTn5hBFL369JRTsAH4xwvk44CBBF74SyQkfwdwaCDBGQvDbI2e6CgVqV19CNT8fX_AyMant_luLB6fHhIzhqnn8wKMYTJKZlr27n6fcRfP91zwU3QuLHs6IbkjE4JqdHFi8W2OjwVpAHZReBC_olFZm1vLAXaGZDPQIJWUWzKMlyio5WPIuyIl9yxtgmT3n1CAlGiFdg89SwRcY18cGa67AZzcW3S6IUD7zVQ&state=1ba64f8c892236e20691beab5d42ed97c93a10ddfd893576
RACK_RUN_ONCE   false
RACK_URL_SCHEME http
RACK_VERSION    ["1", "2"]
WARDEN  Warden::Proxy:69923949726820 @config={:default_scope=>:user, :scope_defaults=>{}, :default_strategies=>{:user=>[:rememberable, :database_authenticatable]}, :intercept_401=>false, :failure_app=>#<Devise::Delegator:0x007f30dec74028>}
```

The followings are my code and config settings. Thanks for help.

route.rb:

```
Groupme::Application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" }
  root :to => "groups#index"

    resources :groups do
        member do
        post :join
        post :quit
        end
        resources :posts
    end

  namespace :account do
    resources :groups
    resources :posts
  end

end
```

app/controllers/user/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def facebook
    raise request.env['omniauth.auth'].to_yaml

    @user = User.find_for_facebook_oauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])

    if @user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end
end
```

app/models/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

      has_many :groups
      has_many :posts

      has_many :group_users
      has_many :participated_groups, :through => :group_users, :source => :group

      extend OmniauthCallbacks

      devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
             :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable

      def join!(group)
        participated_groups << group
      end

      def quit!(group)
        participated_groups.delete(group)
      end

      def is_member_of?(group)
        participated_groups.include?(group)
      end

      def self.find_for_facebook_oauth(auth)
        user = User.where(provider: auth.provider, fb_id: auth.uid).first

        unless user
          user = User.create( name:     auth.extra.raw_info.name,
                              provider: auth.provider,
                              fb_id:      auth.uid,
                              email:    auth.info.email,
                              token:    auth.credentials.token,
                              password: Devise.friendly_token[0,20] )
        end

        return user
      end

    end
```

app/views/common/_user_nav.html.erb ( nav bar for login link )

```
<ul class="nav pills pull-right">

    <li>
      <div class="social"> <%=  fb_like(Setting.domain) %>  </div>
    </li>

  <% if current_user %>    

    <li class="dropdown">
      <%= link_to "/account" , :class => "dropdown-toggle", :data => { :toggle => "dropdown" } do %>
        <%= current_user.email %>
      <% end %>

      <%= render_list :class => "dropdown-menu" do |li|
          li << link_to("My Group", account_groups_path)
          li << link_to("My Post", account_posts_path)
          li << link_to("Logout",destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete )
      end %>

    </li>

<% else %>
  <li> <%= link_to( "Sign Up" ,new_user_registration_path) %> </li>
  <li> <%= link_to( "Login", new_user_session_path )  %> </li>   
  <li> <%= link_to( "FB Login", user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook) )  %> </li>   
<% end %>


</ul>
```

and config.yml

```
defaults: &defaults
  hipchat_token: 
  hipchat_room_name: 
  admin_emails: 
    - ""
  google_analytics_key: ""
  default_logo_url: "/logo.png"
  email_sender: ""

development:
  <<: *defaults
  facebook_app_id: XXXX709306
  facebook_secret: "XXXXcf19353d630ddffBBBBBB595"
  app_name: "groupme"
  domain: "http://groupme.dev"   


test:
  <<: *defaults

production:
  <<: *defaults

  facebook_app_id: XXXXX72709306
  facebook_secret: "XXXXcf19353d630ddffBBBBBB595"
  app_name: "groupme"
  domain: "http://dan-group-post.herokuapp.com"
```

and Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record


# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'devise', '3.0.2'
gem "seo_helper", "~> 1.0.2"
gem "open_graph_helper"

gem "rmagick"
gem "carrierwave"
gem "carrierwave-meta"

gem "settingslogic"

gem "anjlab-bootstrap-rails", "2.3.1.2", :require => "bootstrap-rails"
gem "bootstrap_helper", ">= 4.2.2.1"
gem "simple_form", "~> 3.0.1" 
gem "will_paginate", "3.0.3"
gem "font-awesome-rails", "~> 3.2.1.3"

gem "high_voltage"

gem "airbrake"

gem "rvm-capistrano"

gem "omniauth"
gem "omniauth-facebook"
gem "auto-facebook", "0.4"


gem "whenever"

gem "hipchat"

# Cache
gem "dalli"

gem "compass-rails", "~> 1.1.2"

group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem "capistrano"
  gem "capistrano-ext"
  gem "cape"
  gem "binding_of_caller"
  gem "better_errors", "~> 0.9.0"
  gem "magic_encoding"
  gem "annotate"
  gem "powder"
  gem "pry-nav"
  gem "pry-remote"
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem "cape"
  gem "binding_of_caller"
  gem "better_errors", "~> 0.9.0"
  gem "magic_encoding"
  gem "annotate"
  gem "powder"
  gem "pry-nav"
  gem "pry-remote"
end



# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end
```